# Два LIMIT в запросе MySQL

Tags: mysql

У меня есть таблица структура Дерево

Столбцы

```
id main_id content
```

У меня есть запрос

```
SELECT * FROM app_message ORDER BY (main_id = NULL) DESC, id ASC
```

С помощью такого запроса я вытаскиваю Родительские строки С конца в дочернии с начала

Вопрос как мне добавить в этот запрос условие чтобы ограничить вывод родительских строк но не ограничивать дочерние строки ?

Comment: Сделать UNION двум отдельным запросам

Comment: *С помощью такого запроса я вытаскиваю Родительские строки С конца в дочернии с начала* Не смешите. `ORDER BY (main_id = NULL) DESC, id ASC` эквивалентно `ORDER BY id ASC`.

Comment: Да уже увидел что это не работает